# Multiple comparison operators in a JavaScript boolean expression

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check whether the variable y is less than x and greater than z, but this boolean expression is returning false for some reason. Does JavaScript allow boolean expressions to be written concisely like this? If so, what is the correct syntax?

```
x = 2;
y = 3;
z = 4;

if(x > y > z){
    alert("x > y > z"); //Nothing happens!
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Try using the logical **and** operator:

```
if (x > y && y > z) {
```

to guarantee both conditions are true.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/3sxvy/

If you need to put this into a function, you could try:

```
function compareNumbers(direction) {
    var inOrder = (function () {
        if (direction === "desc") {
            return function (current, before) {
                return current <= before;
            };
        } else if (direction === "asc") {
            return function (current, before) {
                return current >= before;
            };
        }
    })();
    var valid = true;
    for (var i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (!inOrder(arguments[i], arguments[i-1])) {
            valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}

if (compareNumbers("desc", 33, 5)) {
    console.log("Good");
} else {
    console.log("Bad");
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kn6M4/1/

Comment: It would be better if I could create a function that would actually be able to parse "concise" boolean expressions like the one above.

Comment: The problem is that your "concise" expression has a meaning in JavaScript, but a different one (see my answer).

Comment: @AndersonGreen I don't know if it helps, but I added a function that could do the same as what the comparison is (in either ascending or descending order), with as many numbers as you pass to the function. It will really only work for numbers in the same ascending/descending order.

Answer (score 7):

Change your test to

```
if (x > y && y > z){
```

When you write `(x > y > z)`, this is equivalent to `((x>y)>z)`, so you're comparing a boolean `(x>y)` to `z`. In this test, `true` is converted to `1`, which isn't greater than `2`.

Comment: this answer is the best, as its concise, it gives the solution and explains why the syntax used by the OP is valid but has a different meaning in JS, bravo!

Answer (score 7):

You want

```
if(x > y && y > z){
    alert("x > y > z"); //Nothing happens!
}
```

Javascript will try to parse your original statement from left to right and you'll end up comparing z to a boolean value which will then be parsed to a number (0 or 1).

So your original statement is equivalent to

```
if( (x > y && 1 > z) || (x <= y && 0 > z))
```

Comment: That's not as concise as the original, unfortunately. I was hoping that JavaScript would actually allow this kind of concise boolean expression syntax.

Comment: Yes, but it has the slight benefit of *working*! The original is evaluated left to right I believe, meaning once the first part was evaluated, the next evaluation would be `if(true > z) {` which makes no sense. The same mechanism that would allow your example to be more concise would not allow things like `var x = y || z || g;` which is a greater benefit than syntactical sugar.

Comment: @Ocelot20 thats correct, but JS will actually cast it to a number for the conversion, so its really equivalent to the statement in my updated answer.  Which kind of makes sense but clearly isn't what the OP intended.

Comment: @ben336: Right I guess by "makes no sense" I meant, like you said, that it wasn't the original intent.