# Javascript multiple comparison expressions syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax, boolean

By *gut-feeling* I know the following to be wrong syntax, or at least not working as intended (tried it), but there is no error thrown either:

```
var x = 2;
if (1 < x < 3) ...
```

I guess the VM evaluates part of the expression first, then compares it to the rest, but does anybody actually know (with documentation link, preferably) what **exactly** is going on here?

*Edit: I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655959/multiple-comparison-operators-in-a-javascript-boolean-expression?rq=1) that has solutions of how to write this, but I am actually interested in what is happening behind the scenes here.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

```
if (1 < x && x < 3)
```

What you were doing was

```
if (
    (1 < x) // boolean, cast to 0 or 1
    < 3
)
```

[This page from the MDN on operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) explains that `<` is interpreted from left to right.

Comment: Thanks, I am not actually looking for a solution on how to write this, but for answers explaining what is happening (documentation for it).

Comment: @kontur Is my answer clear enough now ? What's missing ?

Comment: Why is `1 < x` evaluated before `x < 3`, and why is this not invalid syntax? Or looking at the *intuitively* expected result, why does this not check if x is within the bounds of 1 and 3.