# comparing multiple variables at same time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

These are my variables.

```
value1= 15.8
value2 = 15.5
value3 = 15.3
```

My condition is, `value1` should be greater than `value2` and `value2` should be greater than `value3`.

> **yes, I can achieve this through `console.log( (value1 > value2) && (value2 > value3))`;**

I tried, `console.log( (value1 > value2 > value3))`;
It looks like fine for me, but it returns `false`.
I want to know whether I can compare three or more variables like this, if yes what I missed here.

Thank you.

Comment: No, it's not possible. The comparison operators are *binary* - they only operate with two values at a time. You can only make a series of binary comparisons.

Comment: **it's not possible**

Comment: there´s only `left- and right-hand` to js-equation

Comment: `value > value2 > value3` will parse as `true > value3` which forces `true` to be evaluated as a number giving you `1 > value3` which is `false`

Comment: [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655959/multiple-comparison-operators-in-a-javascript-boolean-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whether I can compare three or more variables like this

Simple answer, No.

When you do

```
value1 > value2 > value3,
```

its will be parsed from left to right and will look like `(value1 > value2) > value3`

1. value1 > value2: This will yield boolean value, say `true`
2. true > value3: This will always yield false, unless value3 is less than 1 as rightly suggested by [slebetman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167735/slebetman)

When values are compared, JS will try to bring them to same type. So boolean value will be converted to numeric value.

- true -> 1
- false -> 0

Comment: value3 does not need to be zero. Just less than `1`. `true > 0.9` is true and `true > -100` is also true. This is because `new Number(true)` gives you `1`

Answer (score 1):

> **I tried, console.log( (value1 > value2 > value3)); It looks like fine for me, but it returns false.**

okay consider how it's evaluated 
first value1 >value2 is compared which is true,

after that true > value3 is compared which is false.

**I want to know whether I can compare three or more variables like this**

in this case it will be evaluated from left to right, with result left condition to right variable or expression value