# Error while using Nullish coalescing operator operator

Tags: reactjs, null-coalescing-operator

This is the recipe page component

```
const RecipePages = (props) => {

return (
    <div>
        < h5 className="page-header" > Steps</h5 >
        <div className="page-content">
            <ol>
                {
                    str1 = props.props[0].steps.split('\n'),
                    str1.map((elem) => {
                        return (
                            <div>
                                <li>{elem}</li>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })

                }
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div >

)
};
```

This is where I am using ?? operator

```
{
     (0 < items[0].steps.length < 8) ??
         <div className="demoPage page">
            <RecipePages props={items} initial={0} count={items[0].steps.length}></RecipePages>
          </div>
}
```

I am getting the following error

> Error: React.cloneElement(...): The argument must be a React element, but you passed null.

I am trying to print the recipe in a form of a book so I need to add new pages according to the recipe length, that's why I am using this approach.

Comment: `(0 < items[0].steps.length < 8)` doesn't do what we all wish it would -- check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655959/multiple-comparison-operators-in-a-javascript-boolean-expression

Comment: still getting the same error although i changed it to 0 < items[0].steps.length && items[0].steps.length < 8

Answer (score 1):

`(0 < items[0].steps.length < 8)` will return `true` or `false` and the *Nullish coalescing operator* will check for `null` or `undefined`